# Why is this variable still alive?

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I have the following source code.

```
testObj = {}

function testFun()
{
    this.name = "hi";   
}

function test () {

    var instanceOfTestFun = new testFun();

    testObj.pointerToFun = instanceOfTestFun;

    instanceOfTestFun = null;

    console.log(testObj);

}

$(document).ready(test);
```

I expected to see 'null' for the console output of **testObj**, but I see **testFun** function. I thought javascript uses 'pass by ref' for objects.

Please...advise me...

Comment: That's not what passing by reference means.

Comment: `instanceOfTestFun = null;` - this removes the reference to the object, not the object itself. The object is still referenced by another reference - `testObj.pointerToFun` - and therefore, not garbage-collected.

Comment: *"I expected to see 'null' ..., but I see testFun function"* You do? You shouldn't be seeing *any* functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`testObj.pointerToFun` and `instanceOfTestFun` are two references to the same object.

When you write `instanceOfTestFun = null`, you're changing `instanceOfTestFun` to point to nothing.
This does not affect `testObj.pointerToFun`, which still refers to the original object.

If you change the original object (eg, `instanceOfTestFun.name = "bye"`), you will see the change through both accessors, since they both point to the (now-changed) object.

Comment: it makes a lot more sense now...I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = {};
```

The above line creates an object and stores a reference to it inside the variable `x`.

```
var y = x;
```

The above line copies the reference from variable `x` to variable `y`. Now, both `x` and `y` hold references to the object.

```
x = null;
```

The above line deletes the reference that was stored inside `x`. The object that was referenced by this reference is not garbage-collected, since variable `y` still holds a reference to it.

Any given object lives as long as it's referenced by at least one reference.

Comment: Sime Vidas // You again!!! I remember your answers in my other questions!! always very helpful!!!!! appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't destroy the object itself if you set a property that holds a reference to it (`instanceOfTestFun`) to `null`. You can only indirectly destroy an object by removing the last reference to it (which is, at that point, the value held by `testObj.pointerToFun`), so it will be garbage-collected.

Under no circumstance can you delete a property of `testObj` without referencing it.

Don't confuse properties (`instanceOfTestFun`, `testObj`, `testObj.pointerToFun`) with the values they can hold (references to properties, as after `testObj.pointerToFun = instanceOfTestFun`, or plain values, as `9` or `null`).